# Точь-в-точь

Tags: дефис

Правильно ли писать наречие "точь-в-точь" через дефис?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно "точь-в-точь".
Наречия с повторением одно и того же слова всегда пишутся через дефис.
Примеры: *еле-еле, чуть-чуть, как-никак*.

Answer (score 0):

`Точь-в-точь` пишется через дефис.

Comment: @Егор1, Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.